# Grouping touples in a list based on key/value (python)

Tags: python

I have the following list which is comprised of tuples that correlate to key/values:

```
[[1, (62832.0, 1279365864.0, 20361.692513368984, 1729670.0, 7)], [2, (62832.0, 3011978242.0, 47937.01047237077, 60600190.0, 7)], [3, (62832.0, 62832.0, 1.0, 0.0, 7)], [9, (62832.0, 62832.0, 1.0, 0.0, 7)], [18, (62832.0, 18859400.0, 300.15597147950086, 109.0, 7)], [22, (62832.0, 1507339.6799999897, 23.989999999999835, 0.0, 7)], [44, (62832.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 7)], [1, u'18089'], [2, u'34414'], [3, u'1'], [4, u''], [5, u''], [6, u''], [7, u''], [8, u''], [9, u'1'], [10, u''], [11, u''], [16, u''], [18, u'1000.0'], [19, u''], [20, u''], [21, u''], [22, u'23.99'], [23, u''], [24, u''], [25, u''], [26, u''], [27, u''], [28, u''], [29, u''], [36, u''], [37, u''], [38, u''], [39, u''], [40, u''], [41, u''], [42, u''], [44, u'0'], [46, u''], [1, u'24245'], [2, u'64940'], [3, u'1'], [4, u''], [5, u''], [6, u''], [7, u''], [8, u''], [9, u'1'], [10, u''], [11, u''], [16, u''], [18, u'300.0'], [19, u''], [20, u''], [21, u''], [22, u'23.99'], [23, u''], [24, u''], [25, u''], [26, u''], [27, u''], [28, u''], [29, u''], [36, u''], [37, u''], [38, u''], [39, u''], [40, u''], [41, u''], [42, u''], [44, u'0'], [46, u''], [1, 1315.1691906367028], [2, 7784.612385983004], [3, 0.0], [9, 0.0], [18, 10.44030650891055], [22, 0.0], [44, 0.0], [1, 0.0], [2, 0.0], [3, 0.0], [9, 0.0], [18, 0.0], [22, 0.0], [44, 0.0]]
```

What I want to do is pull the key and group them together so something like:

```
[1, (62832.0, 1279365864.0, 20361.692513368984, 1729670.0, 7), u'18089', u'24245'], [2, etc], [3, etc]
```

Any ideas how to do this sort of join/group to the list to

Comment: So take the nested lists, and make them into their own lists? Also, lists don't have keys. ;)

Comment: To start with, I suggest you look at the [data structures](https://docs.python.org/3.3/tutorial/datastructures.html) section of the Python docs.  That will probably answer your questions.  I would also suggest that you post some sample code, if you've got a specific issue with code that you've already written.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that using a defaultdict:

```
from collections import defaultdict

d = defaultdict(list)
for key, value in yourlist:
    d[key].append(value)

result = [[key] + value for key, value in d.items()]
```